# Erratic 500 error on Codeigniter app

Tags: php, codeigniter, error-handling

My CI app has been working well so far.

However I noticed that when a longer SQL query is requested (for example on the home page where around 50 blog posts are shown) there is a serious problem.

Sometimes the page loads fine. Unpredictably, as I reload that same page - with no change in content - the browser keeps hanging until I get back an Apache 500 error. This happens on multiple browsers.

CI error logs show nothing. PHP error logs show nothing.

I've noticed this is not an issue with smaller queries (ie, 20 posts), but am unsure if it has anything to do with the problem, after all, it does download 50 posts on some attempts.

I know this is hard to explain in detail, but if anyone could give me any pointers on how to debug I'd be very grateful. Glad to add any info.

The app is running on a Plesk 9 RHEL server, PHP 5.3.8, MySQL 5.5.17, CI 2.1.0.

php error log file

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 apache       apache              0 May 19 10:46 php_errors.log
```

php.ini info

```
error_log   /var/log/php_errors.log /var/log/php_errors.log
log_errors  On                      On
```

Comment: Does the page call any external calls like twitter etc?

Answer (score 0):

Use the sparks Debug-Toolbar here: http://getsparks.org/packages/Debug-Toolbar/versions/HEAD/show

Then watch the times that your queries take to load, view your memory etc. Slowly increase your post count from 20 to 30 to 50 to 100 etc until the error occurs - and see if something sticks out.

I suspect a PHP timeout is occuring, either because you have the timeout value configured to low (should be around 230), or your query is really poorly written and inefficient, causing the server to take too long to return the result with a larger query.

Comment: i think the query is OK, since the 500 error is intermittent - when there is no error, the page loads in less than a second - looking at my apache logs i see `[Sat May 19 21:27:21 2012] [warn] mod_fcgid: process 21174 graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL
[Sat May 19 21:27:27 2012] [notice] mod_fcgid: process /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/blog/index.php(21174) exit(communication error), get stop signal 9` - this is issued on the 500 error - but not sure what to make of this

Comment: this 500 error code is related to the server not to your code, so you will have to contact the admin of your server and ask him to investigate, since maybe (not sure) its related to your database server which does not serve your request as fast as it should and thats force the fcgid to be killed ..

Comment: the admins said they increased `memory_limit = from 128M to 256M
default_socket_timeout = from 60 to 120` -- sounds overkill? for now, fewer errors

Comment: it would be better if you profiled your application to know how much memory does it use .. and i think try to free some of the autoloaded library from autoload.php

Comment: the debug-toolbar will show you how much memory is being used.